# How do I get the list of all items in dir1 which don't exist in dir2?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, difference

I want to compute the difference between two directories - but not in the sense of `diff`, i.e. not of file and subdirectory contents, but rather just in terms of the list of items. Thus if the directories have the following files:

| dir1 | dir2 |
| --- | --- |
| `f1` `f2` `f4` | `f2` `f3` |

I want to get `f1` and `f4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `comm` to compare two listings:

```
comm -23 <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)
```

- [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) with `<(cmd)` passes the output of `cmd` as if it were a file name. It's similar to `$(cmd)` but instead of capturing the output as a string it generates a dynamic file name (usually `/dev/fd/###`).
- `comm` prints three columns of information: lines unique to file 1, lines unique to file 2, and lines that appear in both. `-23` hides the second and third columns and shows only lines unique to file 1.

You could extend this to do a recursive diff using `find`. If you do that you'll need to suppress the leading directories from the output, which can be done with a couple of strategic `cd`s.

```
comm -23 <(cd dir1; find) <(cd dir2; find)
```

Comment: Also, suggest using `\ls` to avoid use of aliases.

Comment: Aliases are disabled in scripts. If this is something you're typing interactively, then sure, do what you have to do to get the desired output.

Comment: Well, yes, they are, but: 1. You wrote a command, not a generic script and 2. Sometimes people `.`-source scripts, and then aliases aren't disabled.

Comment: Eh, every single command one uses could be aliased. If I wanted to account for aliases I'd have to put a backslash in front of every command in every answer I write.

Comment: But `ls` aliasing is _very_ common. It's probably the most aliased command.

Comment: @einpoklum `\ls` does not avoid use of functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** A naive diff-based solution + improvement due to @JohnKugelamn! :

```
diff --suppress-common-lines <(\ls dir1) <(\ls dir2) | egrep "^<" | cut -c3-
```

Instead of working on directories, we switch to working on files; then we use regular diff, taking only lines appearing in the first file, which `diff` marks by `<` - then finally removing that marking.

---

<sub>Naturally one could beautify the above by checking for errors, verifying we've gotten two arguments, printing usage information otherwise etc.</sub>